# How would I finish activity 'B' and go back to activity 'A'?

Tags: java, android, activity-finish

I have a startup screen with an app I'm working on and when you click the "existing user" button it opens a page to input a username and password. When that is done the user will click "OK" and then the "Processing. May take a few moments." screen pops up with a button to abort which should bring it back to the user info input screen. I just don't know how to get the "Abort" button to work correctly, as I am new to the whole programming thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried finish()? Just call [finish();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) inside activity B where you want to finish, that takes you to previous activity (assuming that is A).

See this [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/difference-between-kill-activity-and-finish-activity/) for an example.

Comment: Okay I'm still new to java particularly, would I create a new method for that or should one exist relating to the button or would it be for the entire class to finish?

Comment: Inside button click listener, you need to call finish().

Comment: Button abortButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button);
abortButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});

Comment: @CameronW : As your example shows it's in an anonymous `OnClickListener` shouldn't it be `ActivityName.this.finish();` ?

Comment: @Squonk: I am not at code right now, but I don't think we need to explicitly refer activityname. Just finish() should work.

Comment: @Nambari : OK. I've coded with Java for 2 years and anonymous classes still confuse me so I wasn't sure. :)